# can't send email to addresses at my own domain

Tags: php, email, dns

I have a simple php script on my domain that sends me an email:

```
...
$toMail = "me@gmail.com"; //this works - I get the email at my gmail
$toMail = "me@mydomain.com"; //this doesn't - I get nothing

mail($toMail, $subject, $message, $header);
```

What setting to I change to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've had this problem myself, when I was redesigning a site recently.

There was an issue with the way our system was set up, so that the system thought that because the email was coming from the same domain it was a spam email and as such blocked it.

Check with your system administrator that you are allowed to be sending the emails etc.

Either that, or you'll have to modify the headers to have look like it's being sent from an external address. Hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 50):

For the people using Google Apps for email, but having your host in other provider this are more detailed instructions for the people that is not very familiar with cPanel.

I could fix the problem of sending email from my domain using a PHP form, when sending the email to an account inside my domain.

i.e. `mydomain.example` Contact form sending email to `contact@mydomain.example`.
The above was not working even if my domain has the correct MX records for the domain using Google Apps.

As Mike noted (and others) above the problem was solved: Adding the MX records into the cPanel.

1. Enter into the cPanel
2. Go the the cPanel Mail section
3. Search for MX Entry Maintenance, sometimes there is no text above the icon.
4. Select the related domain
5. Change **Email** Routing to **Remote Mail Exchanger.**
6. Add all the Google MX records as they are in your domain configuration using the appropriate priority values.
   You can check the records here and priorities
   https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125
7. Double check that **Remote Mail Exchanger.** is selected.

With this setting I was able to send email using mail PHP function to an email account inside the same domain as my website.

Google App instructions talking about MX records
https://support.google.com/a/answer/54717?hl=en

Comment: Solved the problem to me.

Comment: SOLVED after 5 hours thanks to this. Internet gold to you fine sir!

Comment: I am running my server on raw Ubuntu VPS. I do not have any cPanel but I am also facing this issue. Any idea on how can solve it?

Comment: I was working on the same issue for last two days with no luck till i found your answer. Thanks It works Great.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: After spending more than 4 to hrs i got solution here.

Answer (score 13):

The top answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail seems correct to me. The gist of it is that you want the following in your sendmail.mc:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB`, 'example.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY`, 'example.com.')dnl
```

Where `example.com` is the domain in question.

Answer (score 13):

If you use **postfix**, do this :

1. connect to your server via ssh.
2. edit your **main.cf** file :

`nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`

3. comment the following line with **#** :

`# mydestination = ...`

4. add at the end of the **main.cf** document :

`mydestination =`

5. reload your postfix configuration by running :

`/etc/init.d/postfix reload`

Comment: 5. service postfix reload

Answer (score 11):

You need to set an additional parameter on your mail function. On your working example you would need to prepend your email address with '-f' e.g.

`mail($toMail, $subject, $message, $header, "-fme@mydomain.example");`

Comment: `mail($toMail, $subject, $message, $header, "-r me@mydomain.com");` worked for me.

Comment: @redolent This Worked for me too after hours of banging my head. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what does the "-f" do?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it in the following way. I do not store mail locally on the server but use MX records on the registrar to direct mail into Google Apps.  It turned out the MX records needed to be updated in Cpanel as well, as the server was not taking the MX records from the registrar but instead discarding since there was no local MX record or mailbox.  I updated the MX entries on Cpanel to match the registrar's MX entries, and the problem was fixed instantly

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Michael Hellein, the root problem could be your sendmail considering your domain `example.com` email accounts as local accounts. If so, here are few guiding links:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail
- https://serverfault.com/questions/102647/sendmail-to-local-domain-ignoring-mx-records-part-2
- http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2004-September/057382.html
- http://objectmix.com/sendmail/367920-sendmail-ignores-mailertable-some-semilocal-domains.html

But in my case, using FreeBSD 8.2, what really did the trick was:

```
# cd /etc/mail
# vim freebsd.mc
```

Add these two lines:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `example.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `example.com.')dnl
```

Right before:

```
MAILER(local)
MAILER(smtp)
```

Then:

```
# make
```

This is output:

```
cp freebsd.mc host.example.com.mc
/usr/bin/m4 -D_CF_DIR_=/usr/share/sendmail/cf/   /usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4 host.example.com.mc > host.example.com.cf
cp freebsd.submit.mc host.example.com.submit.mc
/usr/bin/m4 -D_CF_DIR_=/usr/share/sendmail/cf/   /usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4 host.example.com.submit.mc > host.example.com.submit.cf
```

Then:

```
# cp sendmail.cf sendmail.cf.bak
# cp host.example.com.cf sendmail.cf
# /etc/rc.d/sendmail restart
```

Hope this saves some headaches to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your email hosted on a different server than the website?  If that is the case the PHP script may be trying to send it internally in which case it'll just disappear, while the other target emails will get put on to the internet and routed properly.

The solution I found was to disable the mail server on your web host, and then PHP will put the message on to the internet to be sent properly.

Answer (score 1):

With PostFix, Debian7, smtp Mailjet

If domain is `my-domain.example`, in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, change

```
mydestination = my-domain.example, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

to

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you can actually send mail to your domain email account and then check your code/email make sure everything is spelled right.. if none of this helped i dont know what went wrong..

Comment: the email at my domain works. I can send and get email there using gmail or whatever. It just wont send with php. The spelling is fine. I've googled around and seen many have the same problem but no good explanation of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, some servers are configured to reject emails missing a valid email address on the sending server. Check that the `$headers` string includes a defined valid email address `From:foo@example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and since I was hosted on another server for e-mail, I just had to disable the local mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few times, and the culprit was if the email was being hosted on another server (e.g. Google Apps). When mail sends to the local domain, it doesn't bother doing a lookup on the MX record and therefore it will not get routed properly. The solution to this problem is just to simply have the mail function disabled on your server by your host.

Comment: I dont understand how disabling the mail function would fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Disabling the mail server meant no email at all was sent! So the fix I did was to remove all local domain names from the `/etc/mail/local-host-names` file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `txt` record is setup correctly for your domain. This usually happens when you do not put this in the `txt` record: `@ (None)   v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue wherein all mails were being perfectly sent to other domains like gmail, live, yahoo etc but all mails would disappear on local domains. 
I had a VPS server with godaddy  which was linux based running Qmail.

I solved the problem by removing the specific domain names in var/qmail/control/virtualdomains file .

Answer (score 0):

SMTP mail server could be an option too.

Answer (score 0):

I spend more than 8 hour on this error and solve it just change the header to any other email address and it will work

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is selecting **Local Mail Exchanger**:

- Go to cPanel
- Select Email Routing
- Select your domain
- Select **Local Mail Exchanger**

**Local Mail Exchanger** will enable you to send an email to an account of the same domain in GoDaddy: e.g.: an email to `info@yourdomain.example`