# Magento doesn't deliver email to interal domain

Tags: email, magento

I have this problem: let's say that my site is *www.mysite.com*; everytime cronjob sends mail to **external domains**, emails are correctly delivered.

But any email that contains *@mysite.com*, which is my domain, isn't. 
I think that magento is trying somehow to deliver email to itself, but our email server is outside on a web hoster (aruba).

I've tried to modify "MX Entry Maintenance" into cPanel, and set that to "Remote", but nothing changed... I don't even know if that's the correct procedure.

How can I fix this? Where do I have to setup this configuration? Inside magento or inside the hoster ?

Comment: This isn't Magento related - this is server configuration.  Your should check with your server administrator.  Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107730/cant-send-email-to-addresses-at-my-own-domain

Comment: Check with your hosting provider to look for mail log entries that indicate the email is being dropped by the SMTP server. MX record mail is often dropped by the remote server because it isn't sent by an authenticated and secured connection. Especially if it's considered to be relayed. All mail services questions that are beyond the scope of this section.