# Google Apps mail does not receive mail from own domain

Tags: email, gmail, google-compute-engine, postfix-mta

I have installed [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) mail server on my Google Compute Engine instance and configured it with [Google Apps SMTP relay service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en). This works great, and I can send e-mails out from my server.

**The problem**

When I send an e-mail to the same e-mail address as the e-mail address used to configure the Google Apps SMTP relay service, It does not receive.

I have tested this by:

```
echo "Test email description" | mail -s "Test mail" -a "From: info@mydomain.com" info@mydomain.com
```

When I tail the `/var/log/mail.log` file you can see that the mail is sent, but when I check the inbox there is no e-mail received.

```
Sep  8 09:19:43 instance-1 postfix/qmgr[24365]: F12AE63011: from=<info@mydomain.com>, size=356, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  8 09:19:43 instance-1 postfix/local[14717]: F12AE63011: to=<info@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep  8 09:19:44 instance-1 postfix/qmgr[24365]: F12AE63011: removed
```

**My `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file:**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.com
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# Use ipv4 protocol
inet_protocols = ipv4

# enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes

# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication.
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd

# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_use_tls = yes

# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107730/cant-send-email-to-addresses-at-my-own-domain) already. You need to edit your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.

Comment the following line:

```
#mydestination = ...
```

And add the line:

```
mydestination =
```

Then reload postfix:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```