# How to modify header of mail that look like it's being sent from an external address in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, header, phpmailer

I need to modify the headers of mail to have look like it's being sent from an external address.

I have problem in sending mail from same domain. For example,

`A(abc@aura.com)` send mail to `B(xyz@aura.com)`

When A send mail to B. B is not able to get mail because of same domain issue. I spent lots of time but nothing helps. Somehow i find that modifying header I can achieve my solution. Here i find little bit solution
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107730/cant-send-email-to-addresses-at-my-own-domain#1107817). But I don't know how to modify it.

I try something like:

```
$mail->setFrom('abc@aura.com', ucfirst($sende_name[0]));
$mail->Sender='abccd@aura.com';
```

But nothing helps.

Any help please.

Comment: It might be a hosting issue.  I had the same problem a while ago and ended up having to set up SFP records in my DNS settings.  Also, if using a major host like GoDaddy just use the built in PHP mail() function.  It is configured to work correctly on their servers.

Comment: @Austin How to set up DNS settings.

Comment: talk with your hosting Company about the problem you are experiencing.  They should be able to walk you through what you need to do.